# Removing all the files with a specific extension using bash

Tags: bash, find

I want to remove all the files with '*.tar.gz' extension using a bash command.
I tried the following, but it didn't work.

```
find . -iname '*.tar.gz' | rm
```

Could you please suggest which command should I use in this case?
Also, could you please tell me why the above command doesn't work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't pipe `rm` to output of `find` output, use `xargs` or `find -exec`:

```
find . -iname '*.tar.gz' -exec rm {} +
```

OR:

```
find . -iname '*.tar.gz' -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} rm {}
```

Comment: Find also has the flag `-delete`: `find . -iname '*.tar.gz' -delete`

Comment: @Jost `-delete` is not specified by POSIX.

Comment: `-delete` is not defined by POSIX, but it is supported by BSD `find`.

Answer (score 6):

`find` itself can delete in some versions, so :

```
find . -iname '*.tar.gz' -delete
```

if you don't have this switch, use anubhava's solution.